# Can Chrome Run jQuery and Javascript at a Time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I was going to run jQuery and Javascript at the same time, but I want to make sure it works before I actually do it. *Can Chrome run both languages at the same time?*

Comment: Dude? - - -______-----

Comment: in fact it looks like you havent read the http://jquery.org /docs

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript

Comment: JQuery isn't a distinct language. It's a library. That's like asking if you can run Java and Swing at the same time.

Comment: ummm ...did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is a library of JavaScript functions. jQuery is written 100% in JavaScript and it just gives you a set of functions that you can use to make things easier/faster to develop.

So yes, you can use them both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript library, so jQuery IS JavaScript. You definitely can use both (jQuery and vanilla JS) through each other, but maybe it's not a good idea to keep your source code readable.

Comment: *"not a good idea to keep your source code readable"* ... what??

Comment: Preferably, I would use either vanilla JS or jQuery. Especially if it comes to selecting elements etc. But that's just an opinion I guess...

Comment: Lots of javascript that is not dom related can be used within jquery code ... and be perfectly consistent and understandable